# BatchHttpLink Apollo with graphql-codegen hooks

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Is it possible to combine multipart/mixed content returned by BatchHttpLink Apollo with graphql-codegen hooks?

"I am trying to configure my BatchHttpLink so that it returns information from batched queries in such a way that it can be retrieved in the data field of the useQuery hook, but it returns undefined in data while the response is in multipart/mixed format.